# How to make a "Roar!" sound?

Tags: sound-effects

Is it possible to produce a lion "roar!" sound without actually recording it from a real lion roaring?

like... only use the sound editor resources to produce a sound that sounds really a "roar!" sound.

Comment: Why bother? There are plenty of samples around that you can use.

Answer (score 3):

Your voice and any basic sound editor should be enough to produce a lion-like roar sound.

1. Get into the mood of acting like a monster. Imagine being really hungry and somebody trying to take your food as you eat. Imagine being a cat/dog/wolf/tiger/lion/bear/dinosaur/dragon in battle against a superior force, where your only chance to win is to intimidate your enemy with a confident and threatening mighty roar.
2. Record a roar with your voice.
3. In the audio editor, slow down the recording to half the speed (50% slowdown). If it is not deep enough, try up to a quarter (75% slowdown).

If your human beast roar is too slow/long the slowed down version might sound tired or bored. Keep recording and try to make your roar as quick as possible. Even if it sounds weird, slowed down it might end up being perfect.

I made a [lion roar video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9CZLSaJhl4) for Audacity years ago. It might be helpful, if you are not familiar with sound editor software yet.

Comment: You read my mind. Well explained! In most software you can adjust pitch without adjusting the time.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old exchange but I might add, for anyone reading this, if you are planning on pitch shifting or time stretching, be sure to record at a high sample rate.  This will generally allow you to shift or stretch the audio further before it disintegrates into an ugly mess of artifacts!

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be mainly down-pitching things, it might worth exploring from your intentionally high pitched voice. (you might try acting as a girl, for example.)

It is embarrassing, but if you pitch it down enough it will becomes a growl anyway, but might be a new result.